# MINUS operation in SQL using query

Tags: sql, database

I have a question regarding the MINUS operation in Database Systems. If  I want to perform a MINUS operation, is it mandatory that both the tables should have same type of Primary/Composite keys?

I am performing the MINUS operation using normal query and not the operator directly. So in order to do that, is it enough to just compare the Primary key in both tables and do the MINUS operation? Or do I need to do compare all the values in the rows?

Comment: Minus is not standard SQL. The standard SQL terrm is EXCEPT. I assume you are using Oracle? This question would be better if you included your tables and example data.

Answer (score 1):

> So in order to do that, is it enough to just compare the Primary key in both tables and do the MINUS operation? Or do I need to do compare all the values in the rows?

The [`MINUS` operation in Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators005.htm) will return "All distinct rows selected by the first query but not the second"  So it has nothing to do with primary keys - it will look at values in all columns.

If you just want to compare primary keys then a `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` operator with a subquery might be more practical.

Comment: So if we compare the primary keys alone (and then fetch the corresponding rows) and not the values in the entire row, will the result still be the same?

Comment: Not necessarily - it depends on if all other columns are equal, given that the primary keys are equal.